# override model field choices option does not pass validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

in Django 1.11:
I have a model field declared like that:

```
a = models.CharField(choices= (('a','a'),('b','b'))
```

In a ModelForm I try to override these choices:

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['a'].choices = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('d', 'd')]
```

The form is rendered correctly (the option 'd' is added), but when submitted a form return an error

```
Select a valid choice. d is not one of the available choices.
```

Whatever I do, nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well the problem is that since you defined choices in the model, the model will do validation as well, so you can only limit *more*, than introducing new ones. Yes one can use some tricks to circumvent this, but it looks like "ugly" modeling.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you think it’s possible to use initial choices as default option but override them at the individual instance level if needed?

Comment: then it makes no sense to specify these in the model. A model is used to store thing in database, and ensure that the object is consistent. The `Form` is responsible for the input of a specific form. SO in that case, it would make sense to drop the `choices`.

Comment: add all possible choices in model and show only a few in different forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `choices` option from the model. It makes no sense to limit what the choices can be if you then allow the user to choose more.

So like

```
    a = models.CharField()
```